# Bulk update add to many-to-many with EF Extended?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, many-to-many, entity-framework-extended

I have a situation where I need to add a new item to a property for a group of objects that has a many-to-many relationship. Is there any way to do this in bulk using EntityFramework.Extended? Something like...

```
Ctx.Foos
   .Where(f => fooIds.Contains(f.FooId))
   .Update(f => f.Bars.Add(bar)) // <-- what would go here???
```

Obviously, the Update() part is not correct. For the time being, I've worked around it by retrieving the set and looping through. Just wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: **NO**

The Update() method allows only to update properties directly related to the entity. Since you want to update a many or many relations (not a property), this library does not allow to do it.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

The best & fastest way if you need performance is by using the Entity Framework Extensions library with the BulkSaveChanges method.

```
Ctx.Foos
   .Where(f => fooIds.Contains(f.FooId))
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(f => f.Bars.Add(bar))

Ctx.BulkSaveChanges();
```